# backing up an AD DC whose Windows Server (2019) installation has died or fixing a 0xc00002e2

Tags: bsod, active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 AD DC where it's just that one and no backup DC (I know, I know) which died yesterday after doing Windows Updates. now whenever it tries to boot it BSODs with `0xc00002e2` and running Directory Services Restore Mode tries to undo an update and fails, or BSODs with `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`. To top it off, I have no idea why it has no restore points. Really cursed.
Running `dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` fails with error 0x8000ffff. Running `dism.exe /image:C:\ /Get-Packages` shows Package_for_DotNetRollup~*snip*~10.0.4057.5 as uninstall pending and Package_for_DotNetRollup~*snip*~10.0.4081.3 as install pending.

**EDIT:** it managed to undo the updates on another DSRM boot and got to the login screen but it often fails booting DSRM with `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED` and well it doesn't boot normally as it BSODs with the `0xc00002e2`

Anyways, I think the only way forward now is to reinstall the OS, but I want to backup the directory. Is there a way to do that? Or what other options have I without reinstalling? I'm dying here

**EDIT2**: it seems the ntds.dit is corrupted but also that the NVME drive is failing precisely in that sector. I tried backing up the file before using esentutl on it and it says a nonsensical message about cyclic copy on Windows, and trying to back it up on Linux yielded a much more scary Input/Output error and on dmesg I get a critical medium error. seems hopeless

Comment: What is an "AC DC"? I assume you're talking about a "DC", but I don't understand what "AC" has to do with this. Do you have a backup system external to the server? Is the server physical or a VM? What updates were being installed? Do you know which one failed?

Comment: @music2myear loool, I meant AD DC. I'm not sure which update failed but DISM from a command prompt from the install media shows Package_for_DotNetRollup~*snip*~10.0.4057.5 as uninstall pending and Package_for_DotNetRollup~*snip*~10.0.4081.3 as install pending.

Comment: @music2myear and running dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions (on cmd from the install media) fails

Comment: Put that info in your question please.

Comment: @music2myear there, thanks